# Angular 2 run interface during http get

Tags: javascript, angular

I've worked out how to import a json object from http get and list the results out via *ngFor.

What I can't work out is how to run an interface against it. My interface file is here:

```
import {Offer} from './offer';
```

and I have my http get request here:

```
constructor(private _httpService: HTTPTestService) { }

offers: "";

onTestGet() {
    this._httpService.getOffers()
        .subscribe(
        data => { this.offers = data.offers; },
    error => alert(error),
    () => console.log("Finished")
    );
}
```

But how do I run the "Offer" interface past the object I get back?

Comment: What exactly do you mean by "run an interface against it"? You mean for auto completion? Then a `offers: Array<Offer> = [];` would suffice.

Comment: Oh I think I might have got confused. The examples I have seen which get data from array use an interface. But I'm just listing out results and that's it. No forms or anything. Do I need to bother with interfaces when getting a json object?

Comment: No, not at all! Only if you need auto completion for the object.

Comment: Ah fantastic many thanks :) Auto completion as in dealing with forms?

Comment: No, in your code while programming! :)

Comment: Haha I got it thanks :) All this terminology in angular 2 is confusing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to be careful with interfaces in TypeScript. Interfaces are only for design and type checking but don't exist at runtime.

You can define an array of `Offer` for offers and cast the data you receive to `Offer[]`. But each element isn't of type `Offer`. This allows to check the structure of objects during compilation...

Here is a sample:

```
constructor(private _httpService: HTTPTestService) { }

offers: Offer[]; // <----

onTestGet() {
  this._httpService.getOffers()
    .subscribe(
      data => { this.offers = <Offer[]>data.offers; }, // <----
      error => alert(error),
      () => console.log("Finished")
    );
}
```

Comment: Ah ok so effectively you need to declare it twice? I'm having problems getting my head around interfaces. Why do I need them? Is it solely to show me the errors when writing code? Could I build an entire project without using them?

Comment: No, it's not mandatory. You can use JS-like code in TypeScript if you want. That being said, type checking is really an interesting feature of TypeScript, so I would recommend to use it ;-) To answer your question, interfaces are only used at designed time / compilation. This will prevent you from problems at runtime...